# what makes my samsung nexus schi515 freeze after calls

Tags: keyboard, system-freeze

When I'm finished with my phone call I have to take the battery out and put it back in for it to even go back to the home screen because it shows a black screen but you can feel vibrations when I touch the  the power button on the side but in order to see my home  screen I have to remove the battery its really frustrating what can I do to fix the problem. It want light up to show my keypad either like to put in my voicemail password

Answer (score 0):

### [LTE data]

[CDMA voice] + [Data]

[Voice off]

=Freeze

If a new battery doesnt fix it - the modem is dying.